Postgresql merge overlapping range only and ignore adjacent
I have couple of ranges, which is using postgresql int8range to tell the start and end number. As we want to find out shared ranges, wondering if there is a way to merge overlapping range only, and ignore adjacent one
NOTE: Seems there is some format issue to type '[' in table, so all the ranges below are '[)'
Original table



Range




[10, 20)


[15, 25)


[30, 25)


[40, 50)


[50, 70)


[60, 80)


[80, 100)



Expected output



Range




(10, 30)


(40, 50)


(50, 80)


(80, 100)



I tried to use function range_agg(), but it will merge both adjacent and overlapping range
https://dbfiddle.uk/Pjq6jHJO
SELECT unnest(ra.mr)
FROM (
    SELECT range_agg(range) AS mr FROM ranges
) AS ra


Sure, updated the fiddle link

If you use numrange and exclusive start (which you do in the question, but not the fiddle), it is similar to what you want. But, otherwise, [1,2) and [2,3) technically touch/overlap.  Where as (1,2) and (2,3) do not ; https://dbfiddle.uk/bv1eaE1W

https://dbfiddle.uk/osOTHeLh

Our purpose is to find out the shared ranges with each item, so although [1, 2) and [2, 3) are touched, but there is no shared range with them
I think there are some issue to type '[' in table body, let me see if I can fix it

Even with int8range it works https://dbfiddle.uk/R36IRRP9 (Note that for integers (20,30) and [21,30) are identical.)

Saying that although [1, 2) and [2, 3) are touched, but there is no shared range is like saying 2-2 and 0 aren't the same. You're not using your own invented maths.

To jump through some hoops of your own making : https://dbfiddle.uk/QQ9HsLrw

Wow, cool! Thanks a lot

create table ranges (range int8range);


CREATE TABLE


insert into ranges (range) values
  ('[10,20)'), ('[15,25)'),
  ('[20,30)'), ('[40,50)'),
  ('[50,70)'), ('[60,80)'),
  ('[80,100)')


INSERT 0 7


WITH
  offset_agg
AS
(
  SELECT
    range_agg(
      int8range(
        lower(range)+1,
        upper(range)
      )
    ) AS mr
  FROM
    ranges
),
  renormalise AS
(
  SELECT
    unnest(mr) AS range
  FROM
    offset_agg
) 
SELECT
  int8range(
    lower(range)-1,
    upper(range)
  )
    AS range
FROM
  renormalise 




range




[10,30)


[40,50)


[50,80)


[80,100)




SELECT 4


fiddle
